# DocuSign iOS URL Scheme/Protocol

Tags: ios, docusignapi

Microsoft Intune MAM policy block data transfer to untrusted apps, based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/apps/app-protection-policy-settings-ios#data-transfer-exemptions, I can add a exemption for DocuSign app, but I need the iOS URL Protocol/Scheme of DocuSign, does DocuSign has that? If so, what's it?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help lists the endpoints. Does that help?

Version v2 and v2.1 are current. v2.1 is recommended for all new applications.

(There are no plans to remove v2 end points. Existing apps that use v2 do not need to update to v2.1 unless they want access to new features or fixes that are not security-related.)

Comment: Thanks, Larry. But REST is not what I am looking for. I want the iOS app URL Scheme just as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: Aah, got it. I will enquire further.